# the behavior when a gnu make phony target happens to be the same as a directory name

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

A makefile has a phony target `libs`, and also a directory `libs` to descend into. On one machine it works well, and another it does not descend into `libs` directory for the `libs` target. In both cases the gnu make version is 3.81, but one on windows and another on a centos.

The top make file:

```
$ cat Makefile

SUBDIRS := libs

.phony: all headers libs exes

  all: headers libs exes

headers libs exes:
        @for d in $(SUBDIRS); do \
          echo -e "\n\n";                                 \
          echo -e "=================\n";                  \
          echo -e "  ++Build subdir $$d  target $(@)\n";  \
          make -f $$d/Makefile DIR=$$d TGT=$(@) $(@);     \
          y=$$?; if [ ! "x$$y" == "x0" ]; then                      \
            echo -e "\n  Error $$y: in top makefile\n"; exit 1; fi; \
          echo ;                                              \
          echo -e "  --Build subdir $$d  target $(@) done\n"; \
          echo -e "=================\n";                      \
        done
```

The sub make file:

```
$ cat libs/Makefile

.phony: headers libs exes

headers libs exes:
        @echo -e "\n\n    **** " submake target $(@) " **** \n\n"
```

That result that does not descend:

```
$ make

=================
  ++Build subdir libs  target headers
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dev2/tmp/tt'

    ****  submake target headers  ****

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev2/tmp/tt'

  --Build subdir libs  target headers done
=================

=================
  ++Build subdir libs  target exes
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dev2/tmp/tt'

    ****  submake target exes  ****

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev2/tmp/tt'
  --Build subdir libs  target exes done
=================
```

I expected it to have a section in the middle with:

```
    ****  submake target libs  ****
```

[Edit] The problem is that `.PHONY:` has to be in upper case, as the answerer suggests, and I verified. The windows version of make does not require this though.

Comment: I have some doubts that the output as shown is produced by these makefiles. Why would `/home/dev2/tmp/tt` be entered?

Comment: Is `/home/dev2/tmp/tt` the toplevel directory?

Comment: Does it work on the Windows machine and not on the CentOS one? Does the case of `libs` differ between the phony target and the directory?

Comment: Yes `/home/dev2/tmp/tt` is the top directory. As in the makefile it uses `make -f` instead of `make -C`, intend to build everything from the top directory so for gdb to see source or header files with fuller path.

Comment: The case of `libs` may not be the issue. I changed all `libs` to `LIBS` on windows, it still works well. Thus it must be that the make on windows is not case-sensitive for `.phony` target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Special targets are case-sensitive.  To make *libs* etc actually be phony targets, you need to spell `.PHONY` thus:

```
.PHONY: all headers libs exes
```

As it is, you have an ordinary rule with a somewhat unusually-named target!

Comment: Verified this is the cause. Only problem is that it is not case sensitive on windows, with yagarto-tools 20100703 version 3.81.