# Makefile rules are always executed despite target existing

Tags: go, makefile

I'm trying to adjust my `Makefile` for [my GoLang project](https://github.com/paul-nelson-baker/the-spins/tree/master). I have several rules which should:

1. Setup a git pre-commit hook (Don't want to commit the binary files and break copyright law by accident)
2. Download an mp3 file via `youtube-dl`
3. Extract a subsection of that video via `ffmpeg`

Previously I was doing this via shellscript and checking for each file manually, but in the act of converting my script to a Makefile I seem to be missing something.

The only rule that doesn't re-run is the pre-hook, but I think that's because I'm not using a variable for my target/rule name?

```
.default: install
.phony: install generate clean

export bin_directory = bin
export asset_directory = data/assets
export song_url = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8cgNLGnnK4
export song_file = ${bin_directory}/nsp-you-spin-me-cover.mp3
export loop_file = ${asset_directory}/spin-loop.mp3

install:
    go install .

generate: $(loop_file)
    go generate ./data

$(loop_file): $(song_file)
    mkdir -p "${asset_directory}"
    ffmpeg -i "${song_file}" -ss 00:01:13.30 -to 00:01:30.38 -c copy "${loop_file}"

$(song_file): .git/hooks/pre-commit
    mkdir -p "${bin_directory}"
    youtube-dl "${song_url}" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --exec "mv {} ${song_file}"

.git/hooks/pre-commit:
    cp ./pre-commit .git/hooks/pre-commit
    chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

clean:
    git clean -xdf
```

UPDATE: I've found this works correctly if I lump all the dependencies onto the `generate` rule like so (which seems like the wrong thing to do)

```
.default: install
.phony: install generate clean

bin_directory:=bin
asset_directory:=data/assets
song_url:=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8cgNLGnnK4
song_file:=$(bin_directory)/nsp-you-spin-me-cover.mp3
loop_file:=$(asset_directory)/spin-loop.mp3

install:
    go install .

.git/hooks/pre-commit:
    cp ./pre-commit .git/hooks/pre-commit
    chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit

$(song_file):
    mkdir -p "${bin_directory}"
    youtube-dl "${song_url}" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --exec "mv {} ${song_file}"

$(loop_file):
    mkdir -p "${asset_directory}"
    ffmpeg -i "${song_file}" -ss 00:01:13.30 -to 00:01:30.38 -c copy "${loop_file}"

generate: .git/hooks/pre-commit $(song_file) $(loop_file)
    go generate ./data

clean:
    git clean -xdf
```

Comment: What is the default target? Also, you defined "generate" as a phony target, but it has a prerequisite. Whenever generate runs, it'll run the prerequisite.

Comment: @bserdar so if a phony target has concrete dependencies, it'll run all those? If that's true, why does the pre-commit hook only get performed once? I've set a default and now, I didn't realize that was required. I've updated the question to reflect

Comment: pre-commit hook is looking for the pre-commit file. If that file is there, it won't run again. Same goes for the loop_file, and song_file. The .phony will make go generate piece run, but I'm not sure about the dependencies. Maybe those files are not there?

Comment: @bserdar, that would make sense but I can run each collectively via `make generate` and then manually verify with `ls` that each file exists like expected

Comment: Could you get rid of the "export" directives? Just declare like bin_directory=bin

Comment: @bserdar it was a good idea, but removing `export` and just using any of ' = ' , '=' , ' := ' , or ':=' showed any difference.

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. I suggest getting rid of all the variables and the phony for generate, bringing it to a working minimal state, and go from there,

Comment: Just because a target is phony does not mean that the recipes for its prerequisites will automatically be run.  The prerequisites will be *checked* if the target itself is built, but those that are up to date will not be rebuilt.  That's how a typical `all` target works, after all.

Comment: So for those of us with limited go knowledge, how do you expect `go install .` to interact with your makefile? Because causing that command to run is the *only* thing that either version of your makefile will do when you run `make` without specifying a target. Or alternatively, just how are you running `make`?

Comment: Note also that the special targets are case-sensitive: `.PHONY` and `.DEFAULT` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25295513/2402272), not that this is responsible for the misbehavior.  Failure to actually declare your targets phony opens up possibilities for them to go unbuilt when otherwise you want them built, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify but I assume you're running `make generate` when you see this behavior.  It's always best when asking questions if you show the command you typed, the output you got (cut and paste and formatted properly) or at least sufficient of it to see the problem, and point out exactly which part of the output is unexpected AND what you expected to happen instead.

Assuming your environment and makefile are accurately described above, then the most obvious cause of the behavior you're seeing is that this command:

```
youtube-dl "${song_url}" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --exec "mv {} ${song_file}"
```

is not updating the timestamp on the output file `$(song_file)`, so it always looks older than the targets that depend on it, so make always rebuilds it.

After you run your makefile, use `ls -l` on all the expected output files and see if their modification times are updated.  If not you may need to add `touch $@` to your rule after the `youtube-dl` command, to make sure it was updated:

```
$(song_file): .git/hooks/pre-commit
        mkdir -p "${@D}"
        youtube-dl "${song_url}" --extract-audio --audio-format mp3 --exec "mv {} $@"
        touch $@
```

Also as mentioned in the comments above, and as described in the GNU make documentation, the special targets are `.DEFAULT` (uppercase) and `.PHONY` (uppercase), not `.default` and `.phony`.  Those latter are simply targets you've defined, just like `foo` or whatever; they have no special meaning to GNU make.  makefiles, like all UNIX/POSIX tools and languages, are case-sensitive so be careful to use the correct case for keywords as described in the GNU make manual (and for the targets you define in your makefile)

Removing the `export` won't change anything: GNU make allows a variable to be assigned and exported on the same line.

Comment: This was the problem. `youtube-dl` was marking the file from December 17, 2018 every time. I'm assuming this was probably some metadata it was trying to populate based on the music or something of that nature. Thanks for figuring it out, even though I forgot to specify that I was trying to run `make generate`

Answer (score 0):

Both of your makefiles start with the line

```
.default: install
```

The intent seems to be to set the default target to `install`.  That doesn't work because the target names are case-sensitive -- you wanted `.DEFAULT`, and also `.PHONY`.  But by happenstance, because of the location of that line in the file, you get a similar effect: the default target is `.default`, and it has `install` as a prerequisite.  The `install` target will therefore be checked on every run, and if no such file in fact exists (remember that it's not actually phony, either) then its recipe will run.

So if you run `make` without specifying a target then `make` will *probably* run the `install` recipe (and otherwise, it won't do anything visible to you).  I can't find any reason to think that `go install` would run `make` recursively, so if in fact you see other rules being run then I conclude that you must be naming a target, and if the rule for `generate` is one of those being run then either that or `.phony` must be the target you're naming, because none of the others have `generate` for a prerequisite.

So think about what happens if you run `make generate` with the original makefile.

- The `generate` target has `$(loop_file)` as a prerequisite, so whatever that expands to is checked.

  - Whatever it expands to, there is a rule for `$(loop_target)` with `$(song_target)` as a prerequisite, so whatever *that* expands to is checked.

    - There is a rule for `$(song_target)` with `.git/hooks/pre-commit` as a prerequisite, so it is checked, and finally
    - the rule for `.git/hooks/pre-commit` has no prerequisite, so no further target is checked.  The recipe for `.git/hooks/pre-commit` will be run if and only if that file does not already exist.  The rule was not running for you, so I guess the file existed.
    - The prerequisite for `$(song_target)` not being found out of date, the only reason for `$(song_target)` to be rebuilt is that it did not already exist.  It appears that in that case your rule will in fact generate it, so well and good.  But then,
  - its prerequisite having been found initially missing or out of date, the recipe for `$(loop_file)` will run, regardless of whether that target itself already exists.  And that appears to be sensible, because the recipe uses `$(song_file)`.
- Finally, *its* prerequisite having been (re)built, the recipe for `generate` will run.  This is sensible if `go generate ./data` will make use of `$(loop_file)` or `$(song_file)`, but otherwise those should not be (ordinary) prerequisites of that target.

Thus, `$(song_file)` needing to be built causes all other targets directly or indirectly depending on it to be rebuilt, too, *and that's the right thing to do*.

---

Now let's think about your second makefile.  I presume that you again run `make generate`, rather than just `make` without specifying a target.  In this case,

- The `generate` target has `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, `$(song_file)`, and `$(loop_file)` as prerequisites, so all of these are checked.  And note well that there is no guarantee about the order in which they are checked or updated. It is incorrect to rely on a particular order, and doing so will bite you in a tender place -- maybe not today, and maybe not tomorrow, but if you count on a specific order then your day will come.

  - none of those targets has any prerequisite designated, so each will be built only if it does not already exist.  As discussed above, that appears to be *wrong* for `$(loop_file)` -- even if it already exists, it ought to be rebuilt if `$(song_file)` is.
- if any of its prerequisites was built, then `generate` will be, too.  That doesn't appear quite right: I don't see why it needs to be rebuilt on account of `.git/hooks/pre-commit`, and if it does not depend *directly* on `$(song_file)` then it's messy and superfluous to name it as a prerequisite.

---

It's hard to be sure what hidden dependencies there may be, but it looks like your original makefile is pretty reasonable, and the behavior you describe is what you should expect.  If you can, though, I'd look at pulling the git hook out from the bottom of the dependency stack, because it doesn't look like anything else actually depends on it.

But if you want different behavior, such as considering a target's prerequisites only if the target does not already exist, then `make`'s model isn't really what you're after.  You can still handle that particular desire by engaging `make` recursively, but in that case I don't see what's gained over your original shell script.